# MS Access MDE on Terminal Server

Tags: ms-access

I deployed an MDE file on the terminal server and when I double clicked the MDE i have the following error. " There isn't enough memory to perform this operation. Close unneeded programs and try again.

I never had any issues on local machine.

I tried de-compiling and compacting and again compiling. I can open other forms but only SwitchBoard is the issue. Any thoughts? Hardly there are 9 links from the MainMenu.

Answer (score 1):

If you're in the console session on the terminal server (at a KVM?), or if you enable "Install Mode" (after you remote desktop, running "CHANGE USER /INSTALL"), does the problem still occur? I don't know of any specific issues with MDE applications over terminal services, but trying those two things will let you know if it's related to the TS configuration, or if it's a problem running that MDE on the server itself.

Can you update the question with the version of both Windows Server and Access you're using? [This Microsoft KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=244439) suggests a problem when you have Windows Server 2003 and Access 2000, so some more detail would be helpful here.